# Decoupling system of two partial differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, systems-of-equations

If I have the following systems of PDE 
$$
u_t+x^2u_{xx}-\dfrac{h_1(t)}{h_0(t)}e^{-(v-u)}-\dfrac{h_0'(t)}{h_0(t)} = 0,\\
v_t-\dfrac{h_0(t)}{h_1(t)}e^{-(u-v)}-\dfrac{h_1'(t)}{h_1(t)} = 0,
$$
where $x\in[-L,L]$ and $t\in (0,T)$, $(h_0(t),h_1(t))$ are solutions to the system ${\bf h}'(t)={\bf M}{\bf h}(t)$. I have the explicit expressions for $h_0(t)$ and $h_1(t)$.

Is there a way of decoupling these PDEs? I think there is a way which could take advantage of the simpler $v$ equation.